# Boost::random::discrete_distribution How to change weights once constructed

Tags: c++, boost, random

I want to change the weights of a discrete distribution every time I sample from the distribution without having to initialize an object every time I draw a new random sample.

The reason for changing weights is that this is part of the particle filter algorithm I am implementing. The reason I don't want to instantiate a new object each time is that I want to set the random seed once externally to the whole program in a controlled manner for repeatable results.

Similar queries are asked here but don't quite answer my specific question:

[Boost random::discrete_distribution How to change weights once constructed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8925545/boost-randomdiscrete-distribution-how-to-change-weights-once-constructed) - advises to initialize on each draw

[Why is boost's random number generation (on a normal distribution) always giving the same values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15747194/why-is-boosts-random-number-generation-on-a-normal-distribution-always-giving) - doesn't change the parameters

The problem is that currently each time in one higher level program I call the function that contains the random number generation, I get the same sequence of random numbers. The numbers should be different.

Here is simplified sample of what I am trying to do.

```
typedef boost::mt19937 RNGType;
RNGType rng;
nParticles = 10;

int main()
{      
  std::vector<int> indices(nParticles);
  int nIterations(5);
  for (int i=0; i<nIterations; ++i)
  {
    // Pseudo code. In the final version the weights will change on each loop
    std::vector<double> weights = { 0.1, 0.4, ..., 0.3 }; // Vector length 10
    indices = filter(weights);
    std::cout << indices << std::endl;
  }
  return 0;
}

std::vector filter(std::vector<double> weights)
{
  std::vector<int> indices(nParticles);
  boost::random::discrete_distribution<int,double> weightdist(weights);
  boost::variate_generator< RNGType, 
      boost::random::discrete_distribution<int,double> >
      weightsampler(rng, weightdist);
  for (int i=0; i<nParticles ; ++i)
  {
    indices[i] = weightsampler();
  }
  return indices;
}
```

This returns, e.g.

```
1,8,9,2,3,5,1,9,9,9 // Good: each number is "random"
1,8,9,2,3,5,1,9,9,9 // Bad: This is the same as the previous line
1,8,9,2,3,5,1,9,9,9
1,8,9,2,3,5,1,9,9,9
1,8,9,2,3,5,1,9,9,9
```

Any ideas on how to get different numbers for each filter function output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're already changing the weights every time because you pass in a new set of weights to the `filter()` function on each call. The reason your example produces the same output for each call is because [`boost::variate_generator`'s](http://www.boost.org/doc/html/boost/variate_generator.html) constructor takes both arguments by value. So you end up making a copy of the RNG on each call, and the changes to the copy's internal state are never seen by the original RNG object.

Change the variate generator's template argument to a reference type

```
boost::variate_generator<RNGType&, boost::random::discrete_distribution<int,double>>
//                             ^^^
//               doesn't copy RNG anymore
```

You may also want to change your `filter()` function signature to

```
std::vector filter(std::vector<double> const& weights)
```

This will avoid unnecessary copying of the input argument on each call.

[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/732f9419b02b62d6)